# Add Shourtcut for a menuItem in vaadin 8

Tags: vaadin, shortcut, vaadin8

How can I add a `shourtkey` for a `menuItem` in `vaadin 8` (8.3)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is currently not possible to add a Shortcout für a single MenuItem.

Answer (score 0):

MenuItem does not have support for shortcuts, but let me propose some workaround. (I haven't test it)

[AbstractComponent](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.html) class provides `addShortcutListener()` and [MenuBar](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/MenuBar.html) extends this class.

```
private void actionX() {
    System.out.println("actionX");
}

private void actionY() {
    System.out.println("actionY");
}

...
MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
private final Command commandX = selectedItem -> actionX();
private final Command commandY = selectedItem -> actionY();
menuBar.addItem("ItemX", commandX);
menuBar.addShortcutListener(new ShortcutListener("escape", KeyCode.ESCAPE, null) {
        @Override
        public void handleAction(Object sender, Object target) {
            actionX();
        }
    });
menuBar.addItem("ItemY", commandY); 
menuBar.addShortcutListener(new ShortcutListener("enter", KeyCode.ENTER, null) {
        @Override
        public void handleAction(Object sender, Object target) {
            actionY();
        }
    });
```